# How to change cursor pointer and apply css on it when someone visits my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a website developer and I wonder if it is possible to **apply some css on the mouse cursor**. I know we can use `cursor:pointer;` and it will turn the standard arrow into a clicking hand (that generally shows the links).

But what I actually want to do is like if **someone visits my website then his mouse cursor turns into RED colour** or **some shadows appear surround it** or something like that. I am not sure if it is possible or not and it may be a very stupid question, so sorry in advance for that. And if it is possible then I want to know, how ?. My question is that simple and any help is really appreciated.

*** Note : If it is possible with javascript or jquery, then I don't mind using these also.**

Thanks

Comment: have a look here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

Comment: This article was really helpful and many thanks for that. But is it not possible to change the color and apply all type of basic css like borders size etc. There were only some predefined designs of cursor but I want to be some more creative with that. Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: I found this that shows someone doing it with Javascript - but that looks rather cumbersome IMO. http://codepen.io/tamm/pen/LIFam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't alter behaviour or style of native cursors, but for your feature you have several options:

First: There's not only `pointer` but a lot of other values for the `cursor` css attribute. You can take a look at them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Secondly: you can provide an image to be used as the cursor. You have to be aware of browser compatibility in this case, but its probably the way to go for you:

`cursor: url('path-to-image.png'), auto;`

---

Another option might be to use `cursor: none` and use some kind of DOM Element which follows the mouse position of the user, instead. Which is probably not the way you want to do it and i wouldn't recommend it (because it just feels hacky and has a negative impact performance wise) but it is definitely possible.

Here's an example of that option (taken from css-tricks.com):
http://codepen.io/tamm/pen/LIFam

Comment: I was aware about some of attributes to cursor : <attribute>; But I pointer for an example. However It was helpful for me to learn new thing, that is DOM element and I will definitely use it for learning purpose. And have a small doubt in mind and that is "If I use an image for cursor, then I think it will take some fractions of second to appear and possibly more with slow connection. I know the image will really small in size but it takes some space."

Comment: Well that depends on your case, but i wouldn't go so far to say that using an image as cursor has significant impact on loading speed of your web-app. Something you should think about instead is user-experience, which is why you don't see many apps having custom cursors.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible you can do like this:

```css
body {
  cursor:url('/img/yourimage.png'), auto;
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way to manually design the cursor ? Suppose if I want to change the color of border of cursor, then also I will have to design an image and then use it.

Comment: hmmmm, ok. Thank you man for your efforts to find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a forked version of the codepen I linked you to

http://codepen.io/hoonin_hooligan/pen/wdGVeG

You'd obviously have to modify things via conventional CSS to make your "cursor" but this would prevent you having to create the cursor as an image and would allow you to have animations etc.

```
 #follower
 position absolute
 top 50%
 left 50%
 #circle1
   position absolute 
   border-top 10px solid transparent
   border-bottom 10px solid transparent
   border-left 15px solid red
   height 0em
   width 0em
   margin-top 0em
   margin-left 0em
```